# picking some items from a list in python: please explain me why this is not working

Tags: python

```
import random
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(numbers)
def sayi(s):
    s[0:4]
    return s

print sayi(numbers)
```

I want to pick first 4 items of the list in order to create a 4-digit number. But I can't do it. Help me please.

Comment: `s[0:4]` will create a new list, it will not modify `s`. So, you need to return the sliced list.

Comment: Also you needn't specify the 0, you can just say `return s[:4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(numbers)
def sayi(s):
    return s[0:4]

print sayi(numbers)
```

You should return the sliced array but you are returning the whole array. Slice won't modify the items in an original array, it creates new array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line: `s[0:4]`

What you're doing here is actually creating a new list and losing all the stuff you did on the original list. You should return the list you've already worked on like this: `return s[0:4]`